# Warning - Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following code:

```
export interface IStartCreate1 {
  (desc?: string, opts?: IDescribeOpts, arr?: Array<string | IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook>, fn?: TCreateHook): void;
  tooLate?: boolean;
}

export interface IStartCreate2 {
  (opts?: IDescribeOpts, arr?: Array<string | IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook>, fn?: TCreateHook): void;
  tooLate?: boolean;
}

export interface IStartCreate3 {
  (arr?: Array<string | IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook>, fn?: TCreateHook): void;
  tooLate?: boolean;
}

export interface IStartCreate4 {
  (fn: TCreateHook): void;
  tooLate?: boolean;
}

export type IStartCreate = IStartCreate1 | IStartCreate2 | IStartCreate3 | IStartCreate4;
```

Then I have an object like so:

```
const v = {
  create: function(){} as IStartCreate
} 

v.create([]);
```

I get this error message:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

I would think an empty array would match `IStartCreate3`

I have looked at other SO questions with a similar error message and I cannot figure this one out!

Comment: This seems to describe the problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017, looks like union types cannot have a call signature:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294

Seems pretty lame.

So I had to do away with the union type and do it a different way, looks like this:

```
export type TArray = Array<string | IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook>;

export interface IStartCreate {
  (desc: string | IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook | TArray,
   opts?: IDescribeOpts | TCreateHook | TArray,
   arr?: TArray | TCreateHook,
   ): void;
  tooLate?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve. Generally speaking, this seems like an extremely complicated type declaration that is likely to cause problems.

Your declaration of `IStartCreate` states that it is *either* a `IStartCreate1` *or* `IStartCreate2` or 3, but we don't know which. You will therefore only be able to access members/signatures on it that exist in *all* of `IStartCreate1`, `IStartCreate2` and `IStartCreate3` (in other words, only `tooLate`). The method signature you're looking for is not in all of them.

If you are sure that `v.create` in fact implements `IStartCreate3`, you can do `(v.create as IStartCreate3)([])`, but it will cause runtime errors if it turns out to be of a different type.

Generally speaking, function overloading doesn't work particularly well in TypeScript, and I would normally try to avoid doing it.

Comment: I agree, in this case, it's for user convenience, and less about type safety, but I generally agree it's better not to overload - it's better to create different methods, each with a particular signature. I added an answer describing that union types aren't "callable".